# What is the difference between fprintf and vfprintf in C++?

Tags: c++, c, access-violation, printf

I haven't been able to find an answer to the following question, and I am having some issues related to the functions.

My main programming is done in C#, and never really learned C++ while studying, but in my current job I have to do some C++ programming aswell.

Most of the C++ programming have been done by a former employee, and he made a function for logging.

Once in a while this function results in an error (Access Violation) - this is not shown to the user, but I see it while running the code through debugger.

When the error happens it points to this line of code:

```
vfprintf( LogFile, fmt, va );
```

I then took a closer look at the code before and after, and to put the above into a context the code around is:

```
void FileLog( char *fmt, ... )
{
  va_list       va;
  struct  time  t;
  struct  date  d;
  long          clk;
  static int    ReEntrant = 0;

  if( FileLogEnabled == false )
    return;

  ReEntrant++;
  if( ReEntrant > 1 )
    return;

  if( LogFile == NULL )
    LogFile = fopen( LogFileName, "a+" );
  if( LogFile != NULL )
  {
    gettime( &t );
    getdate( &d );
    fprintf( LogFile, "\n%d-%02d-%02d %2d:%02d:%02d.%02d0> ", d.da_year, d.da_mon, d.da_day, t.ti_hour, t.ti_min, t.ti_sec, t.ti_hund );

    va_start( va, fmt );
    vfprintf( LogFile, fmt, va );
    va_end( va );

    fflush( LogFile );
    ...
  }
  ReEntrant = 0;
}
```

Actually I dont understand why it is needed (and if it is?) call both fprintf and then vfprintf? I would think the first fprintf call would write the formatted string to the stream (File), and that would be enough?

A little explanation or some information would be much appreciated :)

**EDIT:** After the comment from nos - I tracked down the specific call to the function which today have often been causing this error.

```
FileLog( "TimerRestore[%d], Name=%s", Package.CurGame->Timers[ Index ].Name.c_str() );
```

I indeed think this could cause some trouble, as "TimerRestore[%d], Name=%s" should be followed by a decimal and string arguemtn, however only a string argument is given. I need to do some testing, but Im sure the author who wrote this code meant to write:

```
FileLog( "TimerRestore[%d], Name=%s", Index, Package.CurGame->Timers[ Index ].Name.c_str() );
```

However I still do not understand why the function call does not always seem to result in an error. Or maybe it is cause of the "ReEntrant" variable in FileLog function is blocking it when it does not fail?

Thanks a lot for all the feedback and information.

Comment: Please don't tie together C++ and C in an artificial term "C/C++". They are different languages with different idioms.

Comment: Does this logging function get called from multiple threads?  Are there any statics involved in the `gettime` and `getdate` functions?

Comment: If you look at the code, the first fprintf() call only writes the date/time to the log file. The vfprintf() call prints the actual log message. These can not be combined if the caller has supplied his own formatting string for the log message. However, the actual error is not at the line where your debugger stops, it's because someone calls this function with invalid parameters, which you have to track down.

Comment: Actually nos, it looks like you are right with what is causing the problem. Still I dont completely get why it does not happen every time. I "often" (like 20-30% of the time) happens when this line is executed: FileLog( "TimerRestore[%d], Name=%s", Package.CurGame->Timers[ Index ].Name.c_str() );. Indeed I would think the first string should have 2 arguments, while it only gets 1. But then how come it does not always fail?

Comment: @Knirkegaard That line has an obvious bug, that will cause unpredictable behavior. `TimerRestore[%d], Name=%s"` contains 2 formatting specifiers , "%d" and "%s", but you only supply one argument, the  `Package.CurGame->Timers[ Index ].Name.c_str()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`vprintf()` (and friends) allow to use [`va_list`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdarg/va_list/) as argument, which is useful when your function has a variable amount of arguments:

```
void log(FILE *file, const char* format, ... )
{
  va_list args;
  va_start (args, format);
  fprintf(file, "%s: ", getTimestamp());
  vfprintf (file, format, args);
  va_end (args);
}
```

In your application you can call this function with a variable amount of arguments:

```
log(file, "i=%d\n", i);           // 3 arguments
log(file, "x=%d, y=%d\n", x, y);  // 4 arguments
```

I do not know why your function results in an error. Your code snippet does not provide enough details. The amount of type of provided function arguments *might* be the cause.

Comment: Yeah this is also kind of how the log function is called in the application: void FileLog( char *fmt, ... )

Answer (score 2):

First off, using `fprintf()` and (especially) `vfprintf()` in C++ is **evil.**

To the point: `fprintf()` is a variadic function, it accepts an arbitrary number of arguments. Internally, variadic functions are implemented by "unpacking" the variadic arguments using `va_list`, `va_start()` and `va_end()`.

`vfprintf()` is used when you want to access the functionality of `fprintf()` from your own variadic function *after* you've unpacked your own variadic arguments (that is, you have access to a `va_list` instance). `vfprintf()` is **not** variadic; it accepts a `va_list` storing the arguments.

You haven't posted the declaration of your function calling `fprintf()` and `vfprintf()`, but we can assume it's variadic. It first uses `fprintf()` to print some data into the `LogFile`, and then uses `vfprintf()` to print its own variadic arguments there.

Comment: Can you provide a link or other evidence of it being evil?

Comment: @paddy I don't have a link on hand, but I'll explain myself: `fprintf()` is type unsafe. If you mismatch arguments and format specifiers, it's a runtime error where with iostreams, it would be a compile-time one. Using `vfprintf()` implies writing a (C-style) variadic function, which is again extremely type unsafe. Passing non-trivial classes into such functions is "conditionally-supported with implementation-defined semantics" (quoting the standard).

Comment: Sure, but not being typesafe doesn't make it evil...  It just means you have to be careful.  With proper use, the `printf` family is extremely powerful and is a great tool to have on hand.  Your other point is more reasonable, but I would argue that you never need to pass non-trivial data into the variadic section of a variadic function.  Certainly not one that is going to invoke `vfprintf`.

Comment: @paddy Fair enough. Maybe I just like being melodramatic :-) I'll just add that the fact that you don't *need* to pass nontrivial data doesn't mean you *won't* pass such (e.g. by accident), and if you do, runtime errors lurk.

Comment: Yep certainly, and if you tend to rely on implicit casts from a class into some value (or if you change the return type from some member function one day) then this can turn bad real quick.  I am all for type safety too, but I am quite happy to be flexible in situations where being pedantic doesn't pay off.

Answer (score 1):

`vfprintf` Allows you to have a *variable argument list* which means that you can create your list of parameters dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty common for logging.  You want to make a printf-style log message like:

```
Log("The value of x is now %d", x);
```

But that requires variable arguments.  So you need `vfprintf`.  The reason `fprintf` is used as well is because it wants to write a date/time stamp and you can't add that extra stuff to the existing format passed to `vfprintf`.

Another way to do it is to use the string version `vsprintf`, and make one large string, then write it to file.  But that's more prone to errors (like buffer overflow).